# java Exception: connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, socketexception

I'm trying to invoke a method from another class that means I want to use serialization I make an object of method name and it's parameters and write it on a socket but when I want to make ObjectOutputStream I encounter with error "connection reset by peer: socket write error"
I searched for the possible reasons but I couldn't find any suitable answer

in the server side I didn't close the sockets or I didn't do any work to close that I don't know what happens then :-??

in the line:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = (new ObjectOutputStream(os));
```

and my piece of code is this:

```
InvocationVO invo = new InvocationVO("showStart", treasure, round);

for (int i = 0; i < numPlayer; i++) {
    OutputStream os = socket.get(i).getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = (new ObjectOutputStream(os)); // this has error
    oos.writeObject(invo);

    oos.close();
    os.close();
    Client.getClients()[i].invoke();
}
```

thanks for your helps in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing to a connection that has already been closed by the peer. I find it hard to believe that didn't turn up in your search. The cause of the problem is firstly that you are closing `oos`, and therefore the socket, in this code, so (a) it won't run the second time, and (b) closing the socket causes the peer to get an EOS condition and close the socket, so (c) the second time you run this code you will run into at least two problems.

There is a third problem you haven't hit yet. You are creating a new `ObjectOutputStream` every time you run this code rather than using the same one for the life of the socket. Same goes for `ObjectInputStream` wherever you use it too. If you do what you are doing here you are liable to run into `StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code`.

Comment: really thanks for your answer oh I wrote it wrong and correct it but I still encounter with the same error I couldn't get the sequence of closing the streams and the socket. I have an arrayList of player Sockets in a game that should be open until the game ends, in several methods I have to write or read in some sockets would you please help me on this and say me a practical way to solve it!? thanks a lot

Comment: :what if I write in this way :"(new ObjectOutputStream(socket.get(i).getOutputStream())).writeObject(invo);" but it still have the same error

Comment: @user1323163 Then you still have all the same problems. I don't know why you think that's an improvement. It isn't.

Comment: about that problem when I left that class and worked on another part suddenly I understood that the error doesn't exist any more!!! at last I didn't understand why that happened :( but thanks for your help